GPG cannot generate keys
The files in ~/.gnugpg have been accidentally corrupted and now when I generate a new key I get this error:

gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory Key generation
failed: No such file or directory

How can I recreate the essential files?
Here is the full output minus sensitive data:
gpg --default-new-key-algo rsa4096 --gen-key
gpg (GnuPG) 2.4.4; Copyright (C) 2024 g10 Code GmbH
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Note: Use "gpg --full-generate-key" for a full featured key generation dialog.

GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

Real name: Fred Bloggs
Email address: fred@gmail.com
You selected this USER-ID:
    "Fred Bloggs <fred@gmail.com>"

Change (N)ame, (E)mail, or (O)kay/(Q)uit? o
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
Key generation failed: No such file or directory


Have you try to move .gnugpg  and start from the begin?

Problem resolved. I have found a bug.
For some reason gpg is looking for a specific locale when you run it a second time.
If your locale is EN_AU and en_US then it is missing a file gpg wants. But I searched and found en_UK had the file. So I changed the locale of my machine to UK and it all worked fine after I removed the .gnupg directory.
I am raising the bug with GPG.
I found the bug by running strace and could see which files were missing and were causing the error.
